# Predicate Calculus problem:

Tags: logic

So am studying for my Logic class and I have look for examples but I do not feel like I really get it. I struggle in know how to place the quantifiers, and so.

I tried solving this example, but I would like to know if I am in the right track:

**The problem is to model**:
`"*Any natural number* **n** *has a sucessor that is less or equal to any number strictly greater than* **n**".`

**Using**:
 - naturalNumber/1(naturalNumber(x) will be: x is a natural number)
 - successor/2 (x sucessor of p)
 - leq/2 (x is less than or equal to p)

So far I came up with this answer, but I doubt is correct. Is it is correct, is there any other way to represent it? Am I missing quantifiers?

`∀x∃y ( naturalNumber(x) ^successor(y,x) ) -> (leq(y,p)^ ¬leq(p,x))`

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are missing quantifiers. Your formula contains both $y$ and $p$ unquantified; on the other hand you have an $\exists u$ but no $u$ anywhere else in the formula. And it would be easier if what the original sentence calls $n$ is still called $n$ in your formalization.

Comment: Also, when the English sentence starts with "any natural number" I think it is implicit that everything _else_ that is mentioned -- the successor and the strictly greater numbers -- are also supposed to be natural numbers. I would leave "natural number" out of the formula entirely and specify that the formula is supposed to to be interpreted in the structure $(\mathbb N,{+1},{\leq})$. Unless you do that, you should bound _all_ of the quantifiers with the natural-number predicate.

Comment: I am analyzing your answer, but yea I made a mistake my "u" was supposed to be "y" I miss typed.

Well they are asking for me to use it. Does that mean:

∀n∃y∃p ( ( naturalNumber(n) ^successor(y,n) ) -> (leq(y,p)^ ¬leq(p,n)))

I get what you mean about the naturalNumber.. but if a naturalnumber has a successor, we can say that it will also be a natural number right?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was the answer.
There has to be a number where is a sucessor of "n", which will be called "m", and for every other number "p", that is not less than "m", "m" will be equal or less than "p".

$∀n ( naturalNumber(n) -> ∃m (successor(m,n) ^∀p (¬leq(p,m)-> leq(m,p))) )$